# Просмотр файлов

Tags: php

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {
            echo "$entry\n"."<br>";

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}


?>
```

Как сделать так чтобы просматривались только .html файлы?

Comment: воспользуйтесь функцией `glob("*.html")`

Comment: либо добавьте условия проверки, что имя файла заканчивается на `html` к тому, что у вас уже есть с `.` и `..`.

Comment: @teran а как? гуглю не 1 час, все фуфло через glob который не знаю как прикрутить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для данных целей можно использовать функцию [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php), которая обеспечивает поиск файлов по заданной маске.

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename\n<br>";
    }
```

Если вам необходимо также указать директорию для поиска (помимо текущей), то также указывайте ее в маске поиска, например, `glob("/var/log/*.log")`.

Comment: вопрос как его вкрутить в мой код? я все решения видел но незнаю как все скрестить

Comment: @Павел заменить целиком

Comment: заработало спасибо, не подскажете как организовывается переименование файлов, вот я их вывел которые

Comment: @Павел попробуйте почитать справку по пхп. Там все написано. Для переименования существует функция [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rename.php), параметрами которой являются текущее имя файла, и новое.

Answer (score 2):

загляните в SPL, там можно найти много уже готовых решений

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $fileInfo) {
    if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    if ($fileInfo->getExtension() == 'html') {
        echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: не лучше `isDir()` проверить в первом условии?

Comment: вопрос как его вкрутить в мой код? я все решения видел но незнаю как все скрестить. я это решение уже находил, именно это, в конце еще код не закрыт

Comment: не понял вас. что значит "скрестить"?:)